# Source all vim buffers while keepying my windows / buffers in the same place?

Tags: vim

Basically I'm wanting to source all my vim files without quitting vim when working on a vim script. I understand I can do `so ~/somefile.vim`. My code works but it always leaves me at different windows and buffers.

Here's what I have so far:

In vimrc

```
map <leader>r  :call Reload()<cr>
```

In functions.vim

```
if !exists("*Reload")

    fu! Reload()

    fu! Refresh()
    if &ft == 'vim'| silent so % | endif
    endfu

    messages clear 
    :bufdo call Refresh()
    source ~/.vimrc
    :wa
    :noh

    endfu

endif
```

I tried to set the current buffer at the start then try to restore
my current buffer later but it doesn't work because I think sourcing
happens asynchronous ?

```
let s:buf_now = bufnr()
execute "normal! :b" . s:buf_now
```

The work around would probably be to do create a function that restores my windows with the buffer and windows ids functions maybe ? Add mksession? scriptease ```Runtime`` ? Not sure what the best approach would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iterating over the buffers without using `:bufdo` instead. For example:

```
function! ReloadVimBuffers()
    for i in range(1, bufnr('$'))
        let fname = bufname(i)
        if fname =~# '\.vim$'
            execute 'silent source' fname
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

This is matching the buffer names to `*.vim` rather than looking at filetype detection, which means it would possibly miss your vimrc... If you'd rather use filetype detection instead, you could probably do so with `getbufvar(i, '&filetype')` instead.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help. Your code helped, sorry I'm not sure if I accidentally deleted your comments or they are awaiting approval... I'm new on here. I just did some modifications to the regex, added silent in front of execute, and added the '.' to join the strings. Not sure where to post the finished function for others to see

Comment: @ritchie If you have something that's working for you, then post it as an answer. Posting a self-answer is OK and it's encouraged! Glad this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Based on filbranden's answer:

```
if !exists("*ReloadVimBuffers")
function! ReloadVimBuffers()
    wa
    noh
    messages clear
    for i in range(1, bufnr('$'))
        let fname = bufname(i)
        if fname =~# '^.*\.vim'
            silent execute 'source ' . fname
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
endif
```